# Unable to print in Firefox on Debian

Tags: linux, debian, printing

Here is what I have done on my env.:

```
# Install the driver with the deb file
sudo dpkg -i --force-all brscan4–0.4.10-1.amd64.deb
# Verify that the driver was correctly installed
dpkg -l | grep Brother
# Find all the devices on your network that have the open ports 9100, 515, 631
# The device that has those open ports (and might have the name: (Hon Hai Precision Ind.)) should be your printer/scanner
sudo nmap -p 9100,515,631 192.168.0.0/24
# Setup your printer on your system
brsaneconfig4 -a name=DCP-L2550DW model=DCP-L2550DW ip=192.168.0.0
# Verify that it is set up correctly
brsaneconfig4 -q | grep DCP-L2550DW
```

Here is the evidence that the printer is registered properly:

```
* DCP-L2550DW  [  192.168.0.109]  DCP-L2550DW
```

I am able to scan documents with `gscan2pdf` (printer/scanner). But I am unable to print with Firefox. All I see when I try to print is to export the page into a PDF format.

Is there something I am missing?

More details:

- `uname -r` 4.19.0-20-amd64
- `lsb_release -a`

```
     No LSB modules are available.
     Distributor ID: Debian
     Description:    Debian GNU/Linux 10 (buster)
     Release:        10
     Codename:       buster
```

Answer (score 0):

You needs CUPS to be able to print. SANE is only for scanning.
https://support.brother.com/g/b/faqlist.aspx?c=us_ot&lang=en&prod=dcpl2550dw_us&ftype3=100257 has details (going by the model number in question).

https://support.brother.com/g/b/downloadlist.aspx?c=us_ot&lang=en&prod=dcpl2550dw_us&os=128&mid=true has Debian packages list.